# enter all parameters $ _POST or $ _GET into the function uses the replace string in notepad ++

Tags: php, regex, post

I want to change some code in php file. I just use a text editor notepad ++. I just want to secure destination parameter $ _POST or $ _GET into a function that I made earlier. as in the following example:

Current code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO linkWeb (aaa, bbb, link_name, url_name) VALUES (
'link',
'1',
'$_POST[link_name]',
'$_POST[url_name]')");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO bbb (dsa, bbb, aaa, cczz) VALUES (
'link',
'1',
'$_POST[aaa]',
'$_POST[cczz]')");
```

replace to

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO linkWeb (aaa, bbb, link_name, url_name) VALUES (
'link',
'1',
'function($_POST[link_name]'),
'function($_POST[url_name]')");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO bbb (dsa, bbb, aaa, cczz) VALUES (
'link',
'1',
'function($_POST[aaa])',
'function($_POST[cczz])')");
```

I want to replace all the string **$_POST[aaa]** be a **function($_POST[aaa])**.

I tried using some regex, but not a solution. Please help if you have any other tricks to replace the entire string in the file using notepad ++.
Thanks for the answers that you provide.

Comment: What regex have you tested ? That really seems like the good solution to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Find and replace` tool like so:

- Find: `\$_POST\[.+\]`
- Replace: `function\($0\)` - Where `function` is the name of your function

Make sure *Search Mode* is set to **`Regular Expression`**

---

Look at the screenshot of it working below:

[image: Screenshot]

---

If you want it to work with `$_GET`, change the *Find* statement to `\$_GET\[.+\]`

Comment: No problem! `;)` If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted (press the tick underneath the voting buttons)